# Magento 2.3 - Get product detail by Id

Tags: magento2.3, product-view, order-details

This is my page(My_history)

[image]

From this page, I want to display **detail** of **each product** **by each id**

when I click on link **View order**, **not just one Id** is **array** example, I had researched in the folder, but I do not 
understand, **can anyone help me a hand, please**?

Comment: do you want to get product details when clicking on `view order` or on the current page?

Comment: I want to get product details when I clicking on **view order**

Comment: You need to pass `product id` on click `view order` and based on that ID get an order detail

Comment: I am new to Magento so I don't know how to practice yet, Can you spend a bit your time to tell me more clear or maybe about the code

Comment: Hi Kite Hany, you can have a look to this link to get the product details according to the product id : https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/how-get-product-id-sku-magento-2.html

Comment: I already read that document but it just shows one id, I want to display for all id

Answer (score 0):

Get product collection and through that collection get product data.

```
$_productCollection = $block->getLoadedProductCollection();
foreach ($_productCollection as $_product):
echo $_product->getProductUrl();
// add this product url in the view order link 
endforeach;
```

Comment: Where should I put this code, can you show me a full code, it'll take some time, sorry but I am new to Magento so I need a help

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get product data by id

> In your Block FIle

```
protected $_productFactory;


public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory

) {
    $this->_productFactory    = $productFactory;
}
Public function getProductData($productId)
{
     $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($productId);
     return $product;
}
```

> In your phtml File You can

```
$productData = $block->getProductData($productId);
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I would like to ask, how about the **.phtml** file, do I need to create something in there?

Comment: check my Updated answer

Comment: How can I `echo` the product

Comment: you can echo like `echo $productData->getSku();`

Comment: Sorry, I still wonder, I will choose 1 of the two of code (**Using ProductFactory** or  **Using ProductRepository**) and I match the 3rd code  ( block.php File) in the same `block` file, right? Maybe I wrong, Can you give me the full code, please, because I am new to Magento so I really need help, thanks

Comment: you have a block for you phtml file??

Comment: Yes, I already have it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95759/discussion-between-waqar-ali-and-kite-hany).

Comment: check my updaed answer